# Programatically changing Textview height and width

Tags: android, layoutparams

I have a textview that I want to change the width to match_parent and height to remain at wrap_content. It is nested within a horizontal linearlayout. It is the 2nd in 3 textviews each of which has a weight of 1. When this particular fragment is run it sets the other two buttons to

```
previousButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
nextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

TextView

```
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HOME"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="home"
                />
```

I am using the following to try to change the layout in a fragment:

```
homeButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

Comment: The error is rather obvious. You can't cast `ViewGroup` to `LinearLayout`. So I supposed your `TextView`'s parent layout is a `Linear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your TextView parent layout? Linear, Relative or what? 
Sample if LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
homeButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You must create param base on its parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parent is a `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
homeButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already given the layout_width = "0dp" and layout_weight="1". So, when other two buttons will hide. This home button will take full width. But View.INVISIBLE won't remove them from taking width. You should use View.GONE so that even if they are not visible, they shouldn't take width.

INVISIBLE:

```
 This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
```

GONE:

```
 This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
```

You don't need to set Layout Params again on Home TextView.

Comment: The developer has already used the View.GONE property programmatically